# Pass Class as Parameter into another Classes method

Tags: java

Im trying to pass AirlineTicket into a method addPoints in the Class Customer. I want the Customer.addPoints() method to be able to access the value of AirlineTicket.getPrice()

Customer.java

```
public class Customer {

private String name;
private String address;
private int membershipNumber;
private int membershipPoints;

public void applyPoints(Class AirlineTicket){
    int ticketPrice = AirlineTicket.getPrice();

}

//zero-argument constructor
public Customer() {
    super();
}

//3-argument constructor with points set to 0
public Customer(String name, String address, int membershipNumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.membershipNumber = membershipNumber;
    membershipPoints = 0;
}

//to-string
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer [name=" + name + ", address=" + address + ", membershipNumber=" + membershipNumber
            + ", membershipPoints=" + membershipPoints + "]";
}

//public getters protected setters
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
protected void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
protected void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public int getMembershipNumber() {
    return membershipNumber;
}
protected void setMembershipNumber(int membershipNumber) {
    this.membershipNumber = membershipNumber;
}
public int getMembershipPoints() {
    return membershipPoints;
}
protected void setMembershipPoints(int membershipPoints) {
    this.membershipPoints = membershipPoints;
}



}
```

AirlineTicket.java

```
public class AirlineTicket {

private Customer passenger;
private Flight flight;
private double price;

//zero-argument constructor
public AirlineTicket() {
    super();
}

//3-argument constructor
public AirlineTicket(Customer passenger, Flight flight, double price) {
    super();
    this.passenger = passenger;
    this.flight = flight;
    this.price = price;
}
//to-string
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AirlineTicket [passenger=" + passenger + ", flight=" + flight + ", price=" + price + "]";
}

//public getters and protected setters
public Customer getPassenger() {
    return passenger;
}
protected void setPassenger(Customer passenger) {
    this.passenger = passenger;
}
public Flight getFlight() {
    return flight;
}
protected void setFlight(Flight flight) {
    this.flight = flight;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
protected void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you actually trying to pass a variable of type Class?  Or a variable of type ClassA?

Comment: Follow Java naming conventions and use meaningfully descriptive names and you'll find that your code becomes a lot easier to understand.  Currently you have a variable called `ClassA` of type `Class`.  You haven't shown us a class called `Class` so we don't know what getters/setters it has.  But naming a variable the same name as another class doesn't make it an instance of that other class.

Comment: Very nice.  Now what exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public void applyPoints(Class AirlineTicket){`

One problem is that this is not a variable of type `AirlineTicket`.  You have a variable of type `Class`.  I think you would want something like this:

`public void applyPoints(AirlineTicket ticket){`

And then you can do

`int ticketPrice = ticket.getPrice();`